# Json in c# with arrays and objects

Tags: c#, json

I'm new with Json format, I'm trying to write a c# program that uses Json format, How to write this Json in C#?

```
{    
 "request": [         
  {            
   "md5": "8dfa1440953c3d93daafeae4a5daa326",         
    "features": [          
    "te",              
    "av", 
    "extraction"       
    ],    
     "file_name": "example.xls"   
      "te": {             
           "reports": [              
           "xml",               
           "pdf"              
           ]           
         }             
        "extraction": {            
          "method": "pdf"          
           }        
         }  
      ] 
   }
```

## Here is my try:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
      {
       myJson myjson = new myJson
            {
                md5 = "8dfa1440953c3d93daafeae4a5daa326",
                file_name = "example.xls",
                featurs = new[] { "te", "av", "extraction" },
                reports = new[] { "xml", "pdf" },
                extraction = new ext( "pdf")
            };
               string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myjson,   Formatting.Indented);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
        }

        public class myJson
        {
            public string md5 { get; set; }
            public string[] featurs { get; set; }
            public string file_name { get; set; }
            public string[] reports { get; set; }

            public ext extraction { get; set; }


        }
        public class ext
        {
            private string method;

            public ext(string ex)
            {
               this.method = ex;
            }
            //public string method { get; set; }
        }
```

## Here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

output...

```
{
  "request": [
    {
      "md5": "8dfa1440953c3d93daafeae4a5daa326",
      "features": [
        "te",
        "av",
        "extraction"
      ],
      "file_name": "example.xls",
      "te": {
        "reports": [
          "xml",
          "pdf"
        ]
      },
      "extraction": {
        "method": "pdf"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

code...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var req = new myRequest
    {
        request = new[] {
        new myJson
                    {
                        md5 = "8dfa1440953c3d93daafeae4a5daa326",
                        file_name = "example.xls",
                        features = new[] { "te", "av", "extraction" },
                        te = new te { reports = new[] { "xml", "pdf" } },
                        extraction = new ext { method = "pdf" }
                    }
        }
    };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}

public class myJson
{
    public string md5 { get; set; }
    public string[] features { get; set; }
    public string file_name { get; set; }
    public te te { get; set; }
    public ext extraction { get; set; }
}

public class myRequest
{
    public myJson[] request { get; set; }
}

public class te
{
    public string[] reports { get; set; }
}

public class ext
{
    public string method { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: see `"request": [       ` on the second line in the Json, how can I add this please?

Comment: @user9250580 Updated.

Comment: still doesn' work, can you check again please?

Comment: @user9250580 looks good to me, the output is identical to the example output you've given as far as I can see.

Comment: That works, thank a lot!!